# vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder open child component in a new window

Tags: windows, vuejs2, electron, vue-component

I'm using vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder for my electron app and I try to figure out how would I deal to open a component in a new window, which practically is a video player. The scenario is the following:

I have a list of movie dialogues with start and end timestamps. As I click on start timestamp per row the new window should open and the video player should start.

At this state I'm able to open a new window as it follows:

```
import { remote } from "electron";

export default {
methods: {
    startVideo(id, startTimestamp) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(id);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(startTimestamp);

      let videoPlayerWindow = new remote.BrowserWindow({
        show: true,
        width: 1440,
        height: 900,
        webPreferences: { plugins: true }
      });
    }
}
}
```

but I don't know how to inject in this case the video-player child component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done something similar so I should be able to set you on the right path here. You may just need to fill in some gaps

You will need to [create a sub page using vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages).

So in your `vue.config.js` add

```
module.exports = {
  //... 
  pages: {
    index: 'src/main.js', // your main window
    video_player: 'src/video_player/main.js' // your video window
  }
}
```

Then, an example component in your `src/video_player/main.js` (This is where you would load your video player component)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

new Vue({
    render: h => h('div', 'This is your video player, use a component here instead')
}).$mount('#app')

// listen for data from the main process if you want to, put this in your component if necessary
ipc.on('data', (event, data) => {
  // use data
})
```

Now in your main process or `src/background.js` you will need to add an event listener to open the window from the renderer process.

```
import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron' // import ipcMain

...

// create the listener
ipcMain.on('load-video-window', (event, data) => {
  // create the window
  let video_player = new BrowserWindow({ show: true,
    width: 1440,
    height: 900,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      plugins: true
    } })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    video_player.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL + 'video_player.html')
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) video_player.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    video_player.loadURL(`app://./video_player`)
  }

  video_player.on('closed', () => {
    video_player = null
  })

  // here we can send the data to the new window
  video_player.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
      video_player.webContents.send('data', data);
  });

});
```

Finally, in your renderer process, emit the event to open the window

```
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron"

export default {
    methods: {
        startVideo(id, startTimestamp) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(id);
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(startTimestamp);

          let data = {id, startTimestamp}

          // emit the event
          ipcRenderer.send('load-video-window', data);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Noah Klayman has done a complete example here https://github.com/nklayman/electron-multipage-example.

You will just need to adapt.